Why are my emails with sendgrid attaching a blank csv?
when attaching a file (csv) to  an email I am sending with SendgridAPI in python, I am receiving the email with the correct file name attached, but the csv is blank and does not contain the content of the original file I am attaching
I am using the following function I have defined
def sendEmail(Addresses: list, fname):
    with open (fname) as f:
        raw_content=f.read()
        encoded_file= base64.b64encode(f.read().encode('utf-8')).decode()
        f.close()
    attachedFile=Attachment(
        FileContent(encoded_file),
        FileName('test.csv'),
        FileType('application/csv'),
        Disposition('attachment')
    )
    for email in Addresses:
        message=Mail(
            from_email='noreply@example.com',
            to_emails=email,
            subject='This is an email',
            html_content='This is an automated test email'
        )
        message.attachment=attachedFile
        sg = SendGridAPIClient(sendgrid_api_key)
        response = sg.send(message)
        return(response)
response=sendEmail(['myEmail@email.com'],'test.csv')

I am receiving the email with an attachment, but when I open test.csv that is attached to the email, it is blank
